# how to remove error controller file in angular js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a simple login page and click event on login button. I am able to display view. But in between I am getting this error on console:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=controllers%2FLoginCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at Error (native)
        at http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:37:417
        at Sb (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:50:510)
        at tb (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:51:78)
        at $get (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:106:331)
        at c.controller.I.appendViewElement (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:387:3265)
        at Object.c.factory._.create.H.render (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:385:16956)
        at Object.c.factory._.create.H.init (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:385:16191)
        at c.controller.I.render (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:387:2221)
        at c.controller.I.register (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:387:1952)
```

Here is my code https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mq2vdmxmx5qbfdd/testapp.zip?dl=0

Please run **index.html** to get error

```
/*global define, require */

define(function (require) {

    'use strict';

    var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

    controllers.controller('LoginCtrl', require('controllers/LoginCtrl'));

    return controllers;

});
```

Comment: define(function (require) { })(require); is my first assumption. I never used require synthax indeed

Answer (score 0):

try to "execute" module , note the extra () parenthesis on the end of file

```
define(function () {
'use strict';

function ctrl($scope, $state) {

    $scope.login = function () {
       alert("--")
    };

}

ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
return ctrl;

}());
```